# Centrify for Apache - silent authentication, works in Chrome but not IE8, get a login box

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, active-directory, centrify

We are trying to setup single sign on / silent authentication via `Apache 2.2.21` `RHEL5`.

Using `Chrome`, it works fine - accesses web pages, no login box, but AD user credentials are available.

Using `IE8` (company standard....), we get the login box - ie its using `Basic Auth` - which after login, shows the expected credentials.

The site is an intranet site and shows as such in the `IE` zone.

The apache config is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost ...:443>
...

SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

SSLCertificateFile    ...
SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
SSLCACertificateFile  ...

<Location />
  AuthName "MarketView Web Access"
  AuthType CENTRIFYDC
  UseCache true
  EnableKerberosAuth true
  EnableNtlmAuth true
  EnableBasicAuth true
  SetAuthUserInfo httpheader
  Require valid-user
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

We have this centrify module installed:

```
/usr/share/centrifydc/apache/lib64/mod_auth_centrifydc_22.so
```

Could it be an AD Policy for IE thats disabling it?  Or is `IE8` just not up to the job... Or using an old version...

Comment: Serverfault.com please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the issue was this bit of config:

```
BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
```

It disabled keep alive and downgrade for IE.  Thus, it worked for Chrome, but not IE.

There were errors in the apache error log - I should have seen them, doh!

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer must have integrated Windows authentication enable to be able to do silent auth and here are the steps:

Enable Integrated Windows Authentication

> Use the following procedure to enable silent authentication on each computer.
>   1. Open Internet Explorer and select Tools > Internet Options
>   2. Click the Advanced tab.
>   3. Scroll down to the Security settings.
>   4. Check the Enable Integrated Windows Authentication box.
>   5. Restart IE

I know you mentioned that the site is an intranet site, just thought I put the steps in adding Web Server to local intranet security zone here for you to verify.
To configure the local in tranet security zone in Internet Explorer:

> 1. Open Internet Explorer and select Tools > Internet Options
> 2. Click the Security tab.
> 3. Click the Local intranet icon.
> 4. Click Sites.
> 5. Click Advanced.
> 6. Type the URL for the Web site you want to make part of the local intranet, then click Add. You can use wildcards in the site address, for example,
>      *://*.mycompany.com
>      When you are finished adding URLs or URL patterns, click Close.
> 7. Click OK to accept the local intranet configuration settings, then click OK to close the Internet Options dialog box.

Please let me know if you need more information.
Shin

Comment: Thanks, but IWA is enabled and site matches the wildcard setting for the trusted site zone.

Comment: When I say matches the wildcard... I mean the site name is "some-name.eu.compdev.com" and the wildcard is "*.compdev.com" - so hopefully that is the correct way to specify it...